# How to have Google Sheets populate a schedule based on checked boxes?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I'm a college student and I'm trying to make it easier to work out my classes for the next semester. I'm planning to copy the info for each class into a sheet (day, time, course number) and then check or uncheck each class to try out different schedule combinations. However I'm not sure how to have it populate an actual visual schedule - ideally checking "Monday at 9-10", for example, would put a box under "Monday" during those times with the course name; unchecking would remove it again. I know I *could* do this with a massive if-then statement, but hopefully there's something a little simpler that would work?

Here's a sample version of my sheet (no formulas) to show what I'm going for.
TIA!
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rMYdi7a6ExyWnx-WxxkjkYmMtZDIEfastSQw487d9BI/edit?usp=sharing

**ETA: screenshots of sample course list + sample schedule.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would suggest including the screenshots of your "control block" that contains the checkboxes and the "view block" the contains the schedule. I think that it would make the post easier to understand, and also will let you play with the document without risking to make it irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Are you open to an alternative option that utilizes Apps Script?